# How to search Facebook's "invitable_friends" results

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook app, and I'd like to allow my users to invite their Facebook friends to my app. The proper endpoint is [`/me/invitable_friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2) which is working well. But towards the bottom of that doc page, they recommend implementing a "search box" to filter the results, yet they don't offer any example of how to do this. I've searched around and haven't found anything.

It doesn't appear as though you can pass additional params for filtering the results. Obviously I can filter the results after the fact, but that's not scalable since the API only returns ~20 users at a time. That limit is modifiable (I believe), though it's of course not wise to bump it too high.

So how can I build a search box interface if I can't pass the search text to the endpoint? I must be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

PS - I'm using the JS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably file a bug.

Based on the documentation the default size is 1000 records (average Facebook friend list size is 300-400)

If you don't see the `next` parameter at the end of the result under `paging` then there are no more results.

Comment: Somehow I missed that in the docs. 1000 is probably sufficient. However, for me it's now a moot point, because while I'm aware this endpoint is intended for "game" apps, I wasn't aware that it would change the verbiage of the login button ("Play now") and the notification "John Doe invited you to play Example App" which isn't going to work for my needs. Thank you though.